# Usage of GridDropDownColumn in RadGrid

Tags: c#, webforms, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I have telerik's RadGrid with four columns:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="CountryConstraintsGrid" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="CountryConstraintsGrid_NeedDataSource"
                    OnItemDataBound="CountryConstraintsGrid_ItemDataBound" OnDeleteCommand="CountryConstraintsGrid_DeleteCommand" Width="50%">
    <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="cntry_id,inv_limit_num">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridDropDownColumn UniqueName="CountryConstraintsListColumn" ListDataMember="Countries" ListTextField="name" ListValueField="cntry_id" HeaderText="Country" DataField="cntry_id" 
                                        DropDownControlType="RadComboBox" EnableEmptyListItem="true" EmptyListItemText="None Selected" EmptyListItemValue="">
            </telerik:GridDropDownColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="<%$ Resources:LabelStrings, DealAccess.NumberOfInvestors %>" DataField="inv_limit_num" DataType="System.Int32">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

            <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn UniqueName="EditColumn" ButtonType="ImageButton" EditImageUrl="images/edit.gif">
            </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
            <telerik:GridButtonColumn UniqueName="DeleteColumn" ButtonType="ImageButton" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="images/delete.gif">
            </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Server side:

```
protected void CountryConstraintsGrid_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    CountryConstraintsGrid.DataSource = CountryConstraints;
}

protected void CountryConstraintsGrid_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{        
}

protected void CountryConstraintsGrid_DeleteCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    var deletedCountryID = (int)(((GridDataItem)e.Item).GetDataKeyValue("cntry_id"));
    CountryConstraints.RemoveAll(countryConstraint => countryConstraint.cntry_id == deletedCountryID);
}
```

`CountryConstrains` is collection of the items, each has fieds: `cntry_id`, `cntry_nm`, `inv_limit_num`.

`Country` has fields: `cntry_id`, `name`.

So, I have collection of `country constraints` items and I want to build grid, columns are strings and images, but during editing, first two fields are: RadComboBox and Input['text'].
Second field works just fine, but I don't understand how to bind data to RadComboBoxes. All possible values of RadComboBox are located in `Countries` item (it doesn't connect directly to CountryContstaint, but they have the same field `cntry_id`).

I tried to google this problems ([telerik's example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/columns-rows/columns/column-types/defaultcs.aspx) and [documentations](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-customize-configure-griddropdowncolumn.html)) and all topics from forums, and I just can't understand how to make it works.

Can anyone help me and explain how to work with `GridDropDownColumn` in right way?

P.S. I know, that it's possible to use `DataSourceID` with SQL source, for example, but I want just load list from the variable in the server side.

Answer (score 1):

You can access dropdowns in ItemDataBound or ItemCreated. Currently we have the same scenario and we implemented it in ItemDataBound. Here is an example of our code, converted from VB to C#.

```
GridEditableItem editItem = (GridEditableItem) e.Item;
RadComboBox combo = (RadComboBox) editItem("CountryConstraintsListColumn").Controls(0);
combo.DataTextField = "name";
combo.DataValueField = "cntry_id";
combo.DataSource = SOURCE;
combo.DataBind();
```

You just need to get source for every dropdown and connect it to the control. There could be some additional lines in order to get the data, already stored there.

We are simply getting the respective control based on the item and column, and we are attaching source ot it.

Hope it helps.